# Transform/Replace dates from a number format to a format of EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy with a String

Tags: java, regex, string, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to do the following: Create a class to transform dates from a number format to a format of "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy" without affecting the rest of the string containing the dates.

For instance, "On 9/6/78, a really cool thing happened..." (there could be more than one date per sentence and even incorrect dates such as "31/31/88" or "11/&&/00" as well  as date like "09/06/1988".) should become "On Wednesday, September 06, 1978, a really cool thing happened..."  I should ignore invalid dates or dates without a year. NOTE that the sentences similar to the sample above are kept in a file; there could be one or more sentence per line in this file; there dates can show more than one per line; the dates are unknown; and there could be invalid dates withing a single line. (I hope that this clarify what I need to do. (By the way as I explained below I already know how to convert a single valid numeric date to the "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy" format using "SimpleDateFormat", but the problem is to parse each line in this file, find a date or dates, (if date is valid, transform it), and then replace the numeric date or dates with the new format.  I hope is it clear NOW!)

I have solved the conversion from a simple single numeric date to the "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy" format by using "SimpleDateFormat", but I baffled by using regex to parse the string sentence, find the date, and replace it back with the new format.  Note that I used the following statement to solve the converstion (I don't list the full solution because it is quite long);

```
// format output EEEE, MM dd yyyy 
SimpleDateFormat write      = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat read       = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat readYy     = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
SimpleDateFormat writeYyyy  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

// dates used for a test conversion     
String[] dates = {
"7/20/1969","7/4/2012",
"9/11/01",      // this should be 2001 (m/d/yyyy = 8 chars, mm/dd/yy = 8 chars
"02/29/1975", "6/11/1956", "31/31/00", "7/&&/88" }
```

Now I have been trying to find a solution which should work but for some reason it does not work.  See next code:

```
String line = "We landed on the moon on 7/20/1969. 7/4/2012 is the Fourth of July.";

// I expect to see "7/20/1969" and "7/20/2012" as output but the following does not
// work:

dateRegex = "^([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])/([1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])/(\\d\\d)|(19|20)\\d\\d$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(dateRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
System.out.println(line);

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found " + p + " at: " + m.start());
    // return the sequences characters matching "dateRegex (or so it should...?)
    System.out.println("Match : " + m.group())  // it does not print 'cause nothing is found
}
// the above code works find with a simpler regex string variable, but nothing like this
// what's worng here?   Is this a wrong "dateRegex" pattern?  Thanks.
```

I'd appreciate any help with proven results.  Thanks.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use String.Format()?

```
String.format("On %s, a really cool thing happened.", DateTimeFormatter.print()DateTime.now());
```

Of course this example uses the far superior Joda Time library. And so should you.

**Update:**
After properly understanding the question (I think) this small example, using standard Java libraries should get you started.

```
package com.company;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "On 9/6/78, a really cool thing happened...";
        SimpleDateFormat replacement = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
        Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w{1,2}/\\w{1,2}/(?:\\w{4}|\\w{2})\\b");
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println(datePattern.matcher(example).replaceAll(replacement.format(now)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and I will try that solution, but in this exercise, I am forced to use "SimpleDateFormat" which is a requirement.  By the way, I forgot to explain that these sentences can have multiple instance of dates, and I don't know or should not know what the sentences are there, for all the sentences are kept in a file. Again thanks, and I will see what I can do with your answer.

Comment: Ok. It works with SimpleDateFormat aswell. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do then. Are you parsing a file, to replace dates? Is the number of dates known? What is the mechanism for determining which date to substitute with?

Say I have the following text: "Blah blah DATE, blah blah blah DATE", should the dates be substituted with the same date? Or different ones?

Comment: It seems that the syntax of your statement is not correct at all.  First of all, where is the DateFormattter class (which library)?  I could only find thru "import javax.swing.text.DateFormatter;" and the "print()" is not supported.  The other thing is that your contruction with two methods one after the under seems to be strange, and unusual.

Comment: Answer some of your questions:

Comment: Itøs in joda time: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ I will update my answer to properly answer the question.

Comment: it seems to work even though I will have to adapt your code slightly because, I want the replacement date to be the same found in the original sentence; thus, I will have to extract the date, reformat it somehow, and then I can possible use your solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Mikkel L0kke, the solution you gave me worked just fine.  I just modified it somewhat to solve my problem.  However, I don't know why your pattern string to find the dates worked perfectly whereas mine didn't even though it is like a "standard" string date pattern used even in some other exercises.  Anyhow, I want to thank you one more time.